# PHP RegEx in retrieving number of backlinks

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this code that queries Google to get the the number of backlinks a certain website has. I want to use it in a SEO report generator I'm making. Problem is I can't get the preg_match to work right. Need help.

```
<?php
    $q = "http://zetcode.com/";
    $url = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=link%3A".urlencode($q)."&btnG=Search";
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $pattern = "/(<div id=\"resultStats\">About ([0-9,]+) results<nobr>)|(<div id=\"resultStats\">([0-9,]+) results<nobr>)/";
    preg_match($pattern, $content, $out);
    $googlelinks = $out[count($out)-1];
    var_dump($out);
?>
```

Here's a sample HTML retrieved content: http://pastebin.com/EMaJmCkJ

Comment: why are you `base64_decode`ing normal html?

Comment: Please show the actual HTML you are trying to parse.

Comment: Here's a sample retreived HTML content: http://pastebin.com/EMaJmCkJ

Don't mind the Base64, I use base64 to store a sample HTML so it doesn't look all cluttery, and I don't have to keep querying google which might get me banned. I forgot to remove the function when I replaced it with file_get_content for posting it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this search url instead:
    https://www.google.co.in/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=link:facebook.com

This url returns html only which can be easily parsed with regex like yo did. Google uses this url for browsers that dont support javascript (try searching with javascript disabled on your browser) . The normal url(the one you used) returns a complex looking javascript that in turn creates the html you see on the page.

```
<?php
    $q = "http://zetcode.com/";
    $url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=link%3A".urlencode($q);
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $pattern = "/(<div id=\"resultStats\">About ([0-9,]+) results)|(<div id=\"resultStats\">([0-9,]+) results)/";
    preg_match($pattern, $content, $out);
    $googlelinks = $out[count($out)-1];
    var_dump($out);
?>
```

Comment: still nothing, I tried it out, the array still returns null :(

Comment: I tested it and got.
    array (size=5)
    0 => string '<div id="resultStats">5 results' (length=31)
    1 => string '' (length=0)
    2 => string '' (length=0)
    3 => string '<div id="resultStats">5 results' (length=31)
    4 => string '5' (length=1)

Comment: Looks like I just needed to unquote the openssl extension thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Check your pattern ..hope it should be varied..inside resultStats one more div is there..If you give the correct pattern it will show the output..one more thing no need to decode the file_get_Contents($url).remove the base_64decode function and try it.

Comment: I know, that's what I clearly need help with, someone who can figure out why my patter won't work